# Build website application using automated build TFS 2010

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010

I try to build a website app. using TFS 2010 automatic builds with a custom build definition template. The build fails when tries to copy the dll references to the Bin folder:
 \Lib\AjaxControlToolkit.Binary.NET4\AjaxControlToolkit.dll" to "..\Portal\Portal.Web\Bin\AjaxControlToolkit.dll". Access to the path '..\Portal\Portal.Web\Bin\AjaxControlToolkit.dll' is denied.

The application is a website and not a web application. In the LIB folder I keep all 3rd party dlls used by the website(such as the ajaxcontroltoolkit) Also both Lib and Bin folders are added to the source control.

Answer (score 2):

The problem that the folder structure you made to and stored in the TFS not correct, because the bin folder should not be stored on the TFS, and the third party libraries should stored in a shared binaries folder, so you will need to adjust your folder structure in the TFS and in your local.

[image]

For more information see this link:

[P&P TFS Guide](http://vstsguidance.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How%20To:%20Structure%20Your%20Source%20Control%20Folders%20in%20Team%20Foundation%20Server&referringTitle=How%20Tos&ProjectName=vstsguidance)